# How to Sort .txt File Items in a List

Tags: python, list

I have a set of coordinates for 2 points (0 and 1) in list `data`:

```
data: [0 [834.5, 211.5]][1 [941.5, 362.5]]\n
[0 [834.5, 213.5]][1 [943.0, 362.5]]\n
[0 [825.0, 206.0]][1 [961.5, 360.0]]\n
[0 [814.0, 201.0]][1 [973.5, 358.5]]\n
[0 [813.0, 200.5]][1 [973.5, 357.5]]\n
[0 [779.0, 184.0]][1 [992.5, 358.0]]\n
[0 [758.0, 174.0]][1 [993.5, 366.0]]\n
[0 [758.0, 173.5]][1 [992.5, 366.5]]\n
[0 [714.5, 160.0]][1 [991.0, 391.0]]\n
[0 [691.0, 154.5]][1 [1012.0, 372.0]]\n
[0 [690.5, 154.0]][1 [1012.0, 372.0]]\n
[0 [648.0, 157.5]][1 [1012.0, 372.0]]\n
[0 [631.5, 164.0]][1 [1012.0, 372.0]]\n
```

I need to put the column starting with 834.5 in `head_x` list, 211.5 in `head_y` list, 941.5 in `foot_x`, and 362.5 in `foot_y`. For the first 9 rows, I used this code:

```
for i in range(4, len(data), 37):
    head_x.append(data[i:i+5])

for i in range(11, len(data), 37):
    head_y.append(data[i: i+5])

for i in range(22, len(data), 37):
    foot_x.append(data[i: i+5])

for i in range(29, len(data), 37):
    foot_y.append(data[i: i+5])
```

However, I am not sure how to deal with numbers like 1012.0. I have tried to write some code that would change the for-loop if the `number > 999`, but each character is an element in the overall large list, so that does not work. I am not really sure how to approach this, so some help would be greatly appreciated.

This was the unfortunate output for `head_x`:

```
['834.5', '834.5', '825.0', '814.0', '813.0', '779.0', '758.0', '758.0', '714.5', '691.0', '[690.', ' [648', '0 [63', '[0 [6', '\n[0 [', ']\n[0 ', ']]\n[0', '0]]\n[', '0]]\n[', '0]]\n[', '0]]\n[', '0]]\n[', '0]]\n[', '0]]\n[', '0]]\n[', '0]]\n[', '0]]']
```

Comment: "in list data:" I can't understand. Is `data` an actual variable in your program? If so, please show code that does not have syntax errors, and make sure it is clear exactly what the type is for everything. If what you are showing is instead the content of a file, then do not write `\n` unless the file actually has a backslash and a lowercase n in the place; and consider if you can re-design the file format to make it easier to parse.

Comment: "This was the unfortunate output for head_x:" What should the output be instead? Why?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel data is a list and an actual variable in the program. I have updated the code in the question to accurately reflect data. I have updated the question with the ideal output; the reason is because these are coordinates. To use cv2.line, I need an integer which (after I use int()) is not the case later on in the list.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any updates to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a different, but similar approach, by using the [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) method.

Here I go line by line, find the start/end indexes of each number, and then slice the `line` string with these. The second argument of `str.find` is the index at which it should start finding the substring, so it progressively moves along as it finds each number.

```py
data = r"""[0 [834.5, 211.5]][1 [941.5, 362.5]]\n
[0 [834.5, 213.5]][1 [943.0, 362.5]]\n
[0 [825.0, 206.0]][1 [961.5, 360.0]]\n
[0 [814.0, 201.0]][1 [973.5, 358.5]]\n
[0 [813.0, 200.5]][1 [973.5, 357.5]]\n
[0 [779.0, 184.0]][1 [992.5, 358.0]]\n
[0 [758.0, 174.0]][1 [993.5, 366.0]]\n
[0 [758.0, 173.5]][1 [992.5, 366.5]]\n
[0 [714.5, 160.0]][1 [991.0, 391.0]]\n
[0 [691.0, 154.5]][1 [1012.0, 372.0]]\n
[0 [690.5, 154.0]][1 [1012.0, 372.0]]\n
[0 [648.0, 157.5]][1 [1012.0, 372.0]]\n
[0 [631.5, 164.0]][1 [1012.0, 372.0]]\n"""

head_x = []
head_y = []
foot_x = []
foot_y = []

for line in data.splitlines():
    left = 4
    right = line.find(",", left)
    head_x.append(line[left:right])
    
    left = right + 2
    right = line.find("]", left)
    head_y.append(line[left:right])
    
    left = line.find(" [", right) + 2
    right = line.find(",", left)
    foot_x.append(line[left:right])
    
    left = right + 2
    right = line.find("]", left)
    foot_y.append(line[left:right])

print(head_x)
```

The fortunate output for `head_x`:

```
['834.5', '834.5', '825.0', '814.0', '813.0', '779.0', '758.0', '758.0', '714.5', '691.0', '690.5', '648.0', '631.5']
```